# Hide or reveal div according to JSON data id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to add a javascript snippet to my code, to reveal or hide a div according to the category ID my Json returns

```html
<div id="community-members-member-content-categories-container">
  <div class="community-members-member-content-category page-text9">
    Romantic
  </div>
  <div class="community-members-member-content-category page-text9">
    Family
  </div>
  <div class="community-members-member-content-category page-text9">
    Outdoors
    &amp;
    wildlife</div>
  <div class="community-members-member-content-category page-text9">
    Wellness
  </div>
</div>
```

inside these divs i have my categories

Below I use javascript feth to fetch the information from the server and insert it into the html, but I couldn't find a way to do this with the categories, as it returns a number and not its content!

```js
const baseURL = `http://mulher.store/clara/admin/api/empresa.php?e=8`;
const empresas = document.querySelector('.empresas');
const galeria = document.querySelector('.galeria');

fetch(baseURL).then((answer) => {
  answer.json().then((response) => {
 
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerHTML = `
      <span>${response.empresa.nome}</span>                  
    `;
    empresas.append(h1);
 
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = `
      <span>${response.empresa.endereco}</span>                  
    `;
    empresas.append(p);

// IMAGES
    response.fotos.map((foto) => {
      const picture = document.createElement('picture');
      picture.innerHTML = `
        <img src="https://remote.la/img/community/${foto.url}" alt="Fotos" />
      `;
      galeria.append(picture);
    });
  });
```

JSON Results:

```json
object      {5}
empresa     {14}
fotos       [10]
instalacao  [8]
servico     [3]
categoria   [4]
  0 :   1
  1 :   2
  2 :   3
  3 :   5
```

for example:

category 1: family
Category 5: sports
this should appear inside the "community-members-member-content-categories-container" divi

[Image categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkQwb.png)

Comment: please show sample of your json response and where in your code you're trying to add category data to the page

Comment: I meant please add it to your question, formatted like code

Comment: edited question, sorry about that

Comment: @Kinglish can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to fully understand your code from the sample.

From what I can understand, you could check the category of the image using a conditional and change the style of the div based on that.

```
// do this for each label/category
if (response.category.includes(1)) { 
   let div = document.getElementById("family")

   div.style.display = "none"
}
```

Using the built-in `.includes()` method, we can check if an array contains a value, or in your case, a number corresponding to a category.

Comment: can i explain better?
I have a static html page
some divs with post categories
<div> family </div>
<div> sports </div>

I have to change the categories dynamically, according to the backend that returns the json listed, in the javascript snippet above I already look for some information like name, address and images... but in the category table it returns numbers... 1 , 2.5 these numbers correspond to categories --- 1 = family, 2 = sports .. I need the snippet to run through the code and display the categories according to the json result

Comment: I updated my answer with a bit more detail. If it doesn't do what you're looking for or you need more clarification, feel free to ask!